# How to write information from browser console into qualtrics datafile using javascript

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm trying to extract information from the browser console into my qualtrics datafile. The code below records reaction time to the first keystroke ('console.log(rt)'). These reaction times are recorded in my browser console, but I'm wondering how I can write that data into my qualtrics datafile. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
  var pageStart = new Date(); 
  var trialstart = pageStart.getTime();
  this.hideNextButton();
  this.hidePreviousButton();
  var that = this;
  Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
    var choiceID = null;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 83: // 'S' was pressed
        choiceID = 1;
        break;
      case 68: // 'D' was pressed
        choiceID = 2;
        break;
    }
    if (choiceID) {
      var day = new Date();
   var trialend = day.getTime();
   let rt = trialend - trialstart;
   console.log(rt);
      Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
      that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
    }
  });
  });
```

**EDITED SCRIPT**

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
  var pageStart = new Date(); 
  var trialstart = pageStart.getTime();
  this.hideNextButton();
  this.hidePreviousButton();
  var that = this;
  Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
    var choiceID = null;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 83: // 'S' was pressed
        choiceID = 1;
        break;
      case 68: // 'D' was pressed
        choiceID = 2;
        break;
    }
    if (choiceID) {
      var day = new Date();
   var trialend = day.getTime();
   let rt = trialend - trialstart;
   var trials ="${e://Field/ed_var}";
    if(trials.length > 0) trials += ",";
   Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('ed_var', trials + rt);  
   Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
      that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
    }
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('ed_var', rt);
```

Where ed_var is an embedded variable that has previously been declared in the survey flow.

Also, you should change addOnload to addOnReady.  addOnload often runs before the buttons are present, which can cause an error when you try to hide them.

**Edit:**
If you create embedded data fields for all the loops in the survey flow, then you could pass their names into the loop as Field 2 and pipe ${lm://Field/2} into your JavaScript:

```
var ed_var = "${lm://Field/2}";
...
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData(ed_var, rt);
```

If you want one variable that contains a comma separated list of trials it would be something like:

```
var trials = "${e://Field/ed_var}";
if(trials.length > 0) trials += ",";
...
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('ed_var', trials + rt);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful! I changed addOnload to addOnReady. I also added the Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('ed_var',rt); after that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);. This is definitely getting me closer - it embedded the variable into my file, but it only recorded the last reaction time and not the reaction time for every trial. Any thoughts?

Comment: You'll either need and embedded data variable for every trial or else pipe the embedded variable into the script then append each new trial to it to create a comma separated list of trial times.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you are saying. The only problem is that I'm using the loop & merge function to display my trials. So, I don't have individual trials that I can append the embedded data variable to. Would you know of a way that I could write into my javascript for it to write to the embedded variable based on the trial it reads from field 1 of the loop & merge (i.e., lm://Field/1)?

Comment: Thanks again very much for your help. I've tried playing around with this today. I added my edited to the original post to include your suggestions. It is writing a comma separated list of reaction times for each of the 12 trials; however, the last 7 trials all appear as '000' despite the fact that I responded (807,882,440,832,479,000,000,000,000,000,000,000). If you have any more thoughts on this, it would be much appreciated. I feel like we're getting close here.

Comment: I can't recreate your issue. How are you getting to the next loop since you hide the NextButton, but then never show it or click it?  What browser are you using?

Comment: Using a timer, the trials are set to auto-advance to the next trial after 1500 ms and cannot be submitted before that. My issue is that the recorded RT time is always the duration of the trial (1500ms) instead of the time to first keystroke.

Comment: I added a timer question and set submit/advance to 1.5 secs and still can't replicate your issue, and have no idea where the 000 is coming from. I would add a setTimeout to the script and lose the timer question. Otherwise, if any timeout with the timer, you won't know what time goes with what loop. You can append a 1500 or NA to the ed_var string in the setTimeout function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it - I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, this solution ended up working:

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var pageStart = new Date();
var trialstart = pageStart.getTime();
this.hideNextButton();
var that = this;
Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
  var choiceID = null;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 83: // 'S' was pressed
      choiceID = 1;
      break;
    case 68: // 'D' was pressed
      choiceID = 2;
      break;
 }
    if (choiceID) {
      var day = new Date();
   var trialend = day.getTime();
   let rt = trialend - trialstart;
  var imageID = "${lm://Field/2}";
  var RTtime = "${e://Field/ed_var}" + "|" +  imageID;
 Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('ed_var', RTtime + rt);
   Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
      that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
    }
  });
  });
```